# Is it possible to constantly display data from a Servlet on a jsp using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a Java Web-Application, that executes commands in the command-line in the background and displays results on the webpage. I already implemented a few commands and everything's working fine, but now I have an asynchronous command that constantly sends data to the command-line until it's stopped. 
I was close to giving up, when I learned about AJAX and I found new hope again, to execute the command through a JavaScript, but now I'm on a dead end again, as I can't find a way to constantly send data to the jsp.

So my question:
**Is it even possible to constantly read from a command-line and constantly foward the output to a jsp until stopped by another button?**

This is the button that should start async reading:

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendRequest();" name="async" value="Start asynchronous reading"/>
```

The following JavaScript-code handles AJAX:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
function sendRequest() {
    url = "../TestServlet";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequest;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(createQueryString());
}

function createQueryString() {
    return "async=true";
}

function handleRequest() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
        alert("Response: "+xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

My Servlet has the following (test-)code for executing a command (i took *ping* for testing, because it similarly sends data regularly, but stops automatically)

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command("ping", "192.168.116.1"); //Test-command
        Process process = pb.start();
        Thread clThread = new Thread(() -> {
            StreamGobbler streamGobbler = new asyncTest.StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), System.out::println); //everything that's printed here with sout should be forwarded to the jsp
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executor.submit(streamGobbler);
            executor.shutdown();
        });
        clThread.start(); 
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Task dispatched");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

The only possible solution I could think of was resetting the readyState to 0, when the command finishes, to create like a loop only stopped when a *Stop-Button* is clicked, but i don't know if that's compilable.

Edit after Jaromanda X' answer: 
To access partial data i changed the if in JavaScript to *readyState==3*, but I still don't know where I should forward the data in my Servlet (probably with *response.getWriter().println();*.

Comment: `xmlhttp.readyState == 4` isnt' true until all the request completes, but, at `xmlhttp.readyState == 3` you can start accessing the data being sent, if it's being sent a piece at a time (I can't tell, I don't java) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: Almost anything's possible, but a JSP creates a page of some sorts (usually), whereas for sending just data you'd want a servlet that accepts the call and starts responding with the data.